# SQL Query to Compare Two Tables and Output Results to Two Reports in Proper Order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing software for a fishing tournament that supports maintaining the waterfront here in Jacksonville and I am learning SQL as I go. For this problem I have no idea where to even start:

I am working in SQL Server 2008 and I have four tables:

```
Anglers, Boats, VIG_FishWeight and VIG_FishAggWeight

Anglers:
Angler_ANID, ANLname, ANFName, ANCity, ANState

Boats:
BT_ANID, BoatName

VIG_Fishweight:
FWAngler_ANID, FWBoatNumber, FWWeight,FWTimeStamp 

VIG_FishAggWeight:
FAAngler_ANID, FABoatNumber,FAggWeight,FATimestamp
```

`VIG_FishWeight` contains a list of all fish weighed.

`VIG_FishAggWeight` contains the sum of all fish weighed by each angler

`ANID` is `Angler ID`, an auto generated number that is consistent across all tables.

The tournament pays the first 25 places in the biggest fish and the greatest aggregate weight tournaments.

If an angler’s aggregate weight is in a higher position than his biggest fish weight, then he is placed in the aggregate tournament.  Basically each angler is ranked in the tournament that will pay him the biggest prize.

I need a query to create two reports, one for biggest fish and one for aggregate that contains:

```
Rank, Boat Number AnglerFNAme, AnglerLName, ANCity, ANState, Weight
```

As I said, I don't have any idea where to begin with this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling that this question is probably of too big a scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would begin with SQL Tutorials, and include the terms "aggregate" and "rank" in your search.

Comment: I would suggest an overhaul before you get too far. For instance, you can condense a few of those tables because your queries are going to handle the aggregate data.

Comment: I'd like to overhaul the DB but it is used for applications to run the tournament and I'm afraid of breaking it.  That's a project for next year...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun I wanted to throw together a single `select` and so I'm curious to see if this does actually produce the result you were trying to describe. It sounds like an angler can only place in one of the two tournaments (and can only place once in the biggest fish as well.)

```
with individual as (
   select
        FAAngler_ANID as AnglerId, FWWeight as Weight,
        rank() over (order by FWWeight desc) as Rnk
    from VIG_FishWeight
), aggregate as (
    select
        FAAngler_ANID as AnglerId, sum(FWWeight) as Weight,
        rank() over (order by sum(FWWeight) desc) as Rnk
    from VIG_FishWeight
    group by FAAngler_ANID
), combined as (
    select
        i.AnglerId,
        /* Aggregate ranking must beat all the Individual rankings to win out.
           Remember there might be multiple fish on the Individual side. */
        case when min(a.Rnk) < min(i.Rnk)
             then 'Aggregate' else 'Big Fish' end as Tournament,
        case when min(a.Rnk) < min(i.Rnk)
             then min(a.Rnk) else min(i.Rnk) end as Rnk,
        case when min(a.Rnk) < min(i.Rnk)
             then max(a.Weight) else max(i.Weight) end as Weight
    from individual as i inner join aggregate as a on a.AnglerId = i.AnglerId
    group by i.AnglerId
), tournament as (
    select
        AnglerId, Tournament, Weight,
        rank() over (partition by Tournament order by Rnk) as TournamentRank
    from combined
)
select Tournament, TournamentRank, AnglerId, Weight
from tournament /* inner join to Anglers table for name, etc. */
where TournamentRank <= 25
order by Tournament, TournamentRank;
```

http://rextester.com/discussion/LBF76134/Ranking-split-across-tournaments

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  Here is the Query I used:

```
INSERT INTO WeightsScoreTable
    (ANFName, ANLName, BNBoatNAme, ANCity, ANState, BNBoatNumber, ANBFWeight, ANAggWeight)
     SELECT p.FAAFName, p.FAALName, p.BAABoatName, p.FAACity, p.FAAState, p.FAABoatNumber, c.FWWeight, p.FAAAggWieght
     FROM FAAReport AS p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     WeightsScoreTable AS n ON n.BNBoatNumber = p.FAABoatNumber LEFT OUTER JOIN
     FWReport AS c ON p.FAABoatNumber =c.FWABoatNumber
     ORDER BY ANBFWeight DESC

     DECLARE @LoopValue INT
     SET @LoopValue = (SELECT COUNT (*)
     FROM WeightsScoreTable)

     WHILE @LoopValue > 0
     BEGIN

     INSERT INTO BigFishScore (ANFName, ANLName, BNBoatName, ANCity, ANState, ANBFWeight, BNBoatNumber)
     SELECT ANFName, ANLName, BNBoatName, ANCity, ANState, ANBFWeight, BNBoatNumber
     FROM WeightsScoreTable
     WHERE (ANBFWeight = (SELECT MAX(ANBFWeight) AS Expr1
     FROM WeightsScoreTable))
     ORDER BY ANBFWeight DESC

     DELETE FROM WeightsScoreTable
     WHERE ANBFWeight
     IN (SELECT MAX(ANBFWeight)
     FROM WeightsScoreTable)

     INSERT INTO AggScore (ANFName, ANLName, BNBoatName, ANCity, ANState, ANAggWeight, BNBoatNumber)
     SELECT ANFName, ANLName, BNBoatName, ANCity, ANState, ANAggWeight, BNBoatNumber
     FWHERE (ANBFWeight = (SELECT MAX(ANAggWeight) AS Expr2
     FROM WeightsScoreTable))
     ORDER BY ANAggWeight DESC

     DELETE FROM WeightsScoreTable
     WHERE ANAggWeight
     IN (SELECT MAX(ANAggWeight)
     FROM WeightsScoreTable)

   SET @LoopValue = (@LoopValue - 1)
END
```

Comment: Since you process "Big Fish" before "Aggregate" this will put the angler in the wrong tournament in the case of a tie in the rankings? Your description seemed to imply that "Aggregate" should be the winner in this case. Also this won't handle ties in the rankings at all although I don't know how likely that is.

Comment: Good point.  There is a time stamp field in the VIG_FishWeight table that I can use to resolve ties.  (First fish weighed wins.)